# Make Chart.js ToolTip different then data

Tags: javascript, chart.js, angular-chart

I am new to front-end development and I am curious what is the best way to have the tooltip in Chart 2.0 and Angular-Charts Beta 1.0 different from the label being passed back?:

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="panel1bar" class="chart-bar" height="229px"
                chart-series="[profile['detail']['freq-histogram'].series]"
                chart-labels="profile['detail']['freq-histogram']['short-labels']"
                chart-data="[profile['detail']['freq-histogram'].data]"
                chart-colours="['#008080']"
                chart-legend="false"/>
```

If only there was an option to set chart-tooltip = "profile['detail']['freq-histogram']['long-labels']"

I only ask this as I am getting a long and short label passed back to me and I want to display the full label on Hover in the tool tip

Answer (score 0):

There should be a chart-options attribute for the canvas. 
You can add it like:  `chart-options="chartOptions"`.

Then on your controller you can change the tooltip template by using this code:

```
$scope.chartOptions = {
     tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>"
}
```

But i am not sure if it works properly in chartjs 2.0. For that you can check this issue here : https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2322

Answer (score 0):

You could pass this to the attribute `chart-options="options"`:

```
$scope.options= {
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                return $scope.profile['detail']['freq-histogram']['long-labels'][tooltipItem[0].index];
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: How would you do this with global configurations?

Comment: In your app `.config()`, you can inject the provider `ChartJsProvider`, which has the global options setter method `ChartJsProvider.setOptions(optionsObject)`.
This though wouldn't fit you since you need to access $scope data to configure it, and this data is not available during `.config()` time

Comment: This is not working as $scope.profile does not exist I am directly accessing  a json object and getting the array of labels

Comment: The user of `$scope.profile` was an example, you should replace that with whatever variable stores your long-labels array.